# Need to get the predicted values into a csv or Sframe or Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

### Prerequisites

1. [Dataset](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) I'm working with is MovieLens 100k
2. Python Packages I'm using is Surprise, Io and Pandas
3. Agenda is to test the recommendation system using KNN (+ K-Fold) on Algorithms: Vector cosine & Pearson, for both User based CF & Item based CF

### Briefing

So far, I have coded for both UBCF & IBCF as below

**Q1.** IBCF Generates data as per input given to it, I need it to export a csv file since I need to find out the predicted values

**Q2.** UBCF needs to enter each data separately and doesn't work even with immediate below code:

```
csvfile = 'pred_matrix.csv'
    with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output,lineterminator='\n')
#algo.predict(user_id, item_id, estimated_ratings)
        for val in algo.predict(str(range(1,943)),range(1,1683),1):
            writer.writerow([val])
```

Clearly it throws the error of lists, as it cannot be Comma separated.

**Q3** Getting Precision & Recall on Evaluated and Recommended values

### CODE

**STARTS WITH**

```
if ip == 1:
    one = 'cosine'
else:
    one = 'pearson'

choice = raw_input("Filtering Method: \n1.User based \n2.Item based \n Choice:")

if choice == '1':
    user_based_cf(one)
elif choice == '2':
    item_based_cf(one)
else:
    sim_op={}
    exit(0)
```

**UBCF:**

```
def user_based_cf(co_pe):
    # INITIALIZE REQUIRED PARAMETERS
    path = '/home/mister-t/Projects/PycharmProjects/RecommendationSys/ml-100k/u.user'
    prnt = "USER"
    sim_op = {'name': co_pe, 'user_based': True}
    algo = KNNBasic(sim_options=sim_op)

    # RESPONSIBLE TO EXECUTE DATA SPLITS Mentioned in STEP 4
    perf = evaluate(algo, df, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'])
    print_perf(perf)
    print type(perf)

    # START TRAINING
    trainset = df.build_full_trainset()

    # APPLYING ALGORITHM KNN Basic
    res = algo.train(trainset)
    print "\t\t >>>TRAINED SET<<<<\n\n", res

    # PEEKING PREDICTED VALUES
    search_key = raw_input("Enter User ID:")
    item_id = raw_input("Enter Item ID:")
    actual_rating = input("Enter actual Rating:")

    print algo.predict(str(search_key), item_id, actual_rating)
```

**IBCF**

```
def item_based_cf(co_pe):
    # INITIALIZE REQUIRED PARAMETERS
    path = '/location/ml-100k/u.item'
    prnt = "ITEM"
    sim_op = {'name': co_pe, 'user_based': False}
    algo = KNNBasic(sim_options=sim_op)

 # RESPONSIBLE TO EXECUTE DATA SPLITS = 2
 perf = evaluate(algo, df, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'])
 print_perf(perf)
 print type(perf)

 # START TRAINING
 trainset = df.build_full_trainset()

 # APPLYING ALGORITHM KNN Basic
 res = algo.train(trainset)
 print "\t\t >>>TRAINED SET<<<<\n\n", res

 # Read the mappings raw id <-> movie name
 rid_to_name, name_to_rid = read_item_names(path)

 search_key = raw_input("ID:")
 print "ALGORITHM USED : ", one
 toy_story_raw_id = name_to_rid[search_key]
 toy_story_inner_id = algo.trainset.to_inner_iid(toy_story_raw_id)

 # Retrieve inner ids of the nearest neighbors of Toy Story.
 k=5
 toy_story_neighbors = algo.get_neighbors(toy_story_inner_id, k=k)

 # Convert inner ids of the neighbors into names.
 toy_story_neighbors = (algo.trainset.to_raw_iid(inner_id)
                    for inner_id in toy_story_neighbors)
 toy_story_neighbors = (rid_to_name[rid]
                    for rid in toy_story_neighbors)
 print 'The ', k,' nearest neighbors of ', search_key,' are:'
 for movie in toy_story_neighbors:
     print(movie)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. IBCF Generates data as per input given to it, I need it to export a csv file since I need to find out the predicted values

the easiest way to dump anything to a csv would be to use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)!

```
import csv

res = [x, y, z, ....]
csvfile = "<path to output csv or txt>"

#Assuming res is a flat list
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in res:
        writer.writerow([val])    

#Assuming res is a list of lists
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(res)
```

Comment: Please check the the code below Q2, Been there tried that. It didn't work.